# Getting IllegalArgumentException while capturing photo from Camera

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, image-capture, android-fileprovider

In my project I am using `FileProvider.getUriForFile` with given **provider_paths.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-files-path name="StrengGeheim" path="/" />
</paths>
```

This I added in my AndroidManifest.xml inside  tag:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

This is my camera Intent code:

```
private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    try {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",getOutputMediaFile());
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_FAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In file Uri the path is something like this **/storage/emulated/0/StrengGeheim/06673da7-876f-4a53-9a3d-288ae033f7ac** and the path of storing image from gallery is also same. But still I am getting below error while capturing photo and app is closing.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.stegano.strenggeheim, PID: 19189
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/StrengGeheim/8bb91a47-d33f-428d-a6ee-1f974e61e63e.png
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:712)
                  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:401)
                  at com.stegano.strenggeheim.fragment.FragmentEncode.getOutputMediaFileUri(FragmentEncode.java:68)
                  at com.stegano.strenggeheim.fragment.FragmentEncode.cameraIntent(FragmentEncode.java:61)
                  at com.stegano.strenggeheim.fragment.FragmentEncode.access$100(FragmentEncode.java:35)
                  at com.stegano.strenggeheim.fragment.FragmentEncode$2.onClick(FragmentEncode.java:111)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1044)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1165)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3134)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4049)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is how I am handling OnActivityResult:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY && data != null) {

                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromData(data, getContext());
                    File mediaFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap, mediaFile);
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "Message", path);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_IMAGE_SAVED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageTextMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
                File file =  new File(fileUri.getPath());
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());
                loadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                saveImage(bitmap, file);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_IMAGE_SAVED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageTextMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_FAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromData(Intent intent, Context context){
    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
}

private String saveImage(Bitmap bmpImage, File mediaFile) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmpImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(),
                new String[]{mediaFile.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/png"}, null);
        fo.close();

        return mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Can someone help, please?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/StrengGeheim/8bb91a47-d33f-428d-a6ee-1f974e61e63e.png` -- your `FileProvider` is mis-configured. Edit your question and post the `FileProvider` metadata XML file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the configuration of AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<paths>
  <external-files-path name="StrengGeheim" path="/" />
</paths>
```

This configuration is for files stored under `getExternalFilesDir()`. That is not where your files are stored, based on your error. Change this to:

```
<paths>
  <external-path name="StrengGeheim" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: But `path` is required attribute in android.

Comment: @JaiPrak: `name` is required in `FileProvider` metadata. `path` is not. In your case, you could set the `path` to also be `StrengGeheim`, since that is where the file is located.

Comment: I put `name` and `path` same as **StrengGeheim** in above xml but no luck new path is `/StrengGeheim/f8ed9663-7a60-436f-ade7-f94761b3ead0.png` and getting `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @JaiPrak: This is a different exception than before. Most likely, that is coming from your `new File(fileUri.getPath())` call, which is wrong. You had the right `File` object to use -- it is what you passed to `FileProvider`. Use that `File`.

Comment: No luck still getting `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @JaiPrak: Then post a separate question, where you provide the Java stack trace of the exception and your code that is triggering the exception.