# Camera is giving very big size image on device

Tags: android, performance, image-processing, android-camera, image-compression

In my project, I am capturing image from the camera. I am taking the full-size image from the app (instead of taking thumbnail). Captured image is of very big size which is **7 to 18 mb**. When I have taken image from my default camera app, the size was roughly **2.5 mb** only. As well as it's taking lot of time(6-10 seconds) to load and save to the folder. This happening only when I am using the android device, on emulator it's working good. This is my code:

```
package com.stegano.strenggeheim.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.stegano.strenggeheim.BuildConfig;
import com.stegano.strenggeheim.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;


public class FragmentEncode extends Fragment {
    private static final String MESSAGE_IMAGE_SAVED = "Image Saved!";;
    private static final String MESSAGE_FAILED = "Failed!";
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/StrengGeheim";
    private static final int GALLERY = 0, CAMERA = 1;
    private File capturedImage;
    TextView imageTextMessage;
    ImageView loadImage;

    public FragmentEncode() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    private void galleryIntent() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        try {
            capturedImage = getOutputMediaFile();
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", capturedImage);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_FAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_encode, container, false);

        imageTextMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.imageTextMessage);
        loadImage =  view.findViewById(R.id.loadImage);

        loadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPictureDialog();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera",
                "Cancel"
        };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                galleryIntent();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                cameraIntent();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (requestCode == GALLERY && data != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromData(data, getContext());
                    File mediaFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap, mediaFile);
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "Message", path);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_IMAGE_SAVED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageTextMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImage.getAbsolutePath());
                    loadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                     saveImage(bitmap, capturedImage);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_IMAGE_SAVED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageTextMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_FAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromData(Intent intent, Context context){
        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    }

    private String saveImage(Bitmap bmpImage, File mediaFile) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmpImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bytes);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(),
                    new String[]{mediaFile.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/png"}, null);
            fo.close();

            return mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() throws IOException {
        File encodeImageDirectory =
                new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);

        if (!encodeImageDirectory.exists()) {
            encodeImageDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        File mediaFile = new File(encodeImageDirectory, uniqueId + ".png");
        mediaFile.createNewFile();
        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: As [I pointed out previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467393/115145), get rid of your `saveImage()` call, and have `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);` tell the camera app the final location to put the photo. If, for some reason, you think that wasting the user's time, CPU, battery, and memory is a good idea, and therefore you want to go through the extra I/O to load and re-save the image yourself, do not use PNG as an image format for photos. Use JPEG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking the image from the camera and getting the File. So, I am saving the image directly in file location which I generated using `getOutputMediaFile()` method. For that I am overloading `saveImage()` method like this:

```
private void saveImage(File mediaImage) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaImage);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    getContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

This method will put the image in the desired file location and also accessible to the Gallery for other apps. This method is same as `galleryAddPic()` method on this link [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

But In the case of picking a photo from the Gallery, I will have to create the **File** in the desired location and write the bytes of the picked image into that file, so the old `saveImage()` method will not change.

In `onActivityResult` method, this is how I used overloaded `saveImage()` method:

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            saveImage(imageFile);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            loadImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), MESSAGE_IMAGE_SAVED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageTextMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is download an available API online, or, if need be, dowload the source code of some online compressor. Then you could use it as a model. Never directly use the source code. One that is widely supported across languages is: https://optimus.keycdn.com/support/image-compression-api/

Comment: I did this from tutorials and stackoverflow. I don't want to use any external api or foliow the same thing they are doing. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: I was saying that you could download an API to compress the photo, which saves time putting it into a folder, not to take a photo with an API @JaiPrak

Comment: Any suggestions, what api?

Comment: You could look at https://optimus.keycdn.com/support/image-compression-api/ it appears to have several languages supported. @JaiPrak